# can't pass challenge if code not optimized further

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I can't pass this coding challenge: Code Challenge: https://www.codewars.com/kata/550f22f4d758534c1100025a/train/javascript

because my code is *TOO SLOW*. I'm not sure which part of my code is causing the problem. That's why I need help to optimize it.

```
function dirReduc(arr){
  if (arr.length === 0 || arr.length === 1) return [];
  let lengthTracker = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
  if (lengthTracker > arr.length) {
    lengthTracker = arr.length;
    i = 0;
  }
    switch(arr[i]) {
  case "NORTH":
 arr[i-1] === "SOUTH"? arr.splice(i-1,2) : 
 arr[i+1] === "SOUTH"? arr.splice(i,2) : null
  break;
  case "SOUTH":
 arr[i-1] === "NORTH"? arr.splice(i-1,2) : 
 arr[i+1] === "NORTH"? arr.splice(i,2) : null
    break;
  case "EAST":
 arr[i-1] === "WEST"? arr.splice(i-1,2) : 
 arr[i+1] === "WEST"? arr.splice(i,2) : null
    break;
  case "WEST":
 arr[i-1] === "EAST"? arr.splice(i-1,2) : 
 arr[i+1] === "EAST"? arr.splice(i,2) : null
    break;
}
i===arr.length-1? i=0:null
  }
 return arr;
}
```

Comment: this expr : `lengthTracker > arr.length`  is always false, you can't compare `undefined` with `number`, farther more  every `arr[i-1]` or `arr[i+1]` would result undefined, and don't modify `arr`, you should return new array  from `dirReduc`, also remove those ternary operator, this make harder to read, And I believe that your code doesn't pass, because it doesn't product expected output...

Comment: Ow! after looking to your code a bit, I realize that  that you use for loop for iteration, because you modify `arr` , it modify `arr.length` also, that make `i < arr.length` never false, so an endless loop

Comment: Also, if the array is long, then splicing it has a lot of overhead.  Effectively making this algorithm `O(n^2)`.  It would probably be better to maintain a separate readpoint indxe and writepoint index into the array.

Answer (score 1):

Splicing can be expensive. We can form a recurrence that assumes the function has already correctly reduced the next part of the list:

```js
function matches(a, b){
  return (a == "NORTH" && b == "SOUTH") ||
    (b == "NORTH" && a == "SOUTH") ||
    (a == "EAST" && b == "WEST") ||
    (b == "EAST" && a == "WEST");
}


function f(A, i=0){
  if (i == A.length)
    return [];
    
  const rest = f(A, i + 1);
  const [head,...tail] = rest;
  
  if (head){
    if (matches(A[i], head))
      return tail;
    else
      return [A[i]].concat(rest);
  }
  
  return [A[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems with this.  First, as I mentioned in the comments, splicing long arrays is costly and makes your algorithm `O(n^2)`.  Simple and faster would be to use a read-point and a write-point to copy the elements into itself one cell at a time, just skipping over the annihilations and then use splice once at the end to trim the uncopied cells off the end of the array.  This would make it `O(n)`.

Secondly, your code is looking both forward and backward for matches which is both unnecessary and can be confusing.  Finally, there's no need for a `switch (...)` as all of the branches do the same thing.

Here is how I would use your code to accomplish this, changing the things mentioned above and noted in the comments.

```
function dirReduc(arr){
    if (arr.length === 0 || arr.length === 1) return [];
    let lengthTracker = 0;                  // the write-point

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {   // i is the read-point
        if(lengthTracker == 0) {
            // if no output, copy readpoint to write-point and advance
            arr[lengthTracker++] = arr[i];
        } else {
            // replaces switch()
            if (((arr[lengthTracker-1] === "NORTH") && (arr[i] === "SOUTH"))
             || ((arr[lengthTracker-1] === "SOUTH") && (arr[i] === "NORTH"))
             || ((arr[lengthTracker-1] === "EAST") && (arr[i] === "WEST"))
             || ((arr[lengthTracker-1] === "WEST") && (arr[i] === "EAST"))) {
                lengthTracker--;    // annihilate by decrementing the writepoint
            } else {
                // copy readpoint to writepoint and advance
                arr[lengthTracker++] = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
    //trim the array to only include what was written
    arr.splice(lengthTracker);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: @גלעדברקן  You’re right, of course.  JS is not my best language and I didn’t have time to test it.

Comment: @גלעדברקן OK, assuming I didn’t mess up my cut-and-paste on my mobile device, it should be fixed now.  I did test it at the site and it passed all tests, both samples and the full attempts.

Comment: Nice, I learned something.

Comment: @גלעדברקן  thanks.  I believe that this type of software pattern is called a “transducer”.

Comment: @RBarryYoung What does write-point and read-point mean? I googled and got no explanation for them.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Truth to be told, I don't understand your code at all. I am unable to grasp the flow of the algorithm or how the answer is provided correctly at the end even after using pythontutor to study it.

Comment: Write-point is the point in the array that you are writing to, read-point is the point that you’re reading from.  They start out the same as zero and the read and write points will be used to copy the input to the output (then incrementing both) until a match is detected, then the write point will decrement while the read point increments, effectively removing the annihilated pair from the output.